# Проблемы с подключение v8 c++ к проекту

Tags: c++

У меня есть папка с v8, с названием v8-main, в ней есть папка include, я подключаю эту папку С/C++ -> Общие -> Дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов -> ставлю на папку include, в исходном коде подключаю через `#include <v8.h>`, далее пытаюсь просто скомпилировать для проверки с этой строчкой `v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;` и получаю ошибку

`error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __cdecl v8::Isolate::CreateParams::~CreateParams(void)" (??1CreateParams@Isolate@v8@@QEAA@XZ).`

`error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __cdecl v8::Isolate::CreateParams::CreateParams(void)" (??0CreateParams@Isolate@v8@@QEAA@XZ).`

Comment: *"Во вкладке Компоновщик -> Общие -> Дополнительные каталоги библиотек, также подключаю include папку, после чего добавляю в обозревателе решений папку include и все файлы и под папки в проект"* - не делайте так, компоновщик не использует include.

Comment: @user7860670, я ошибся, папка include не подключена в компоновщике